# Number of possible build combinations

Tags: diablo-iii

The number of possible Diablo 3 Classic/Vanilla build combinations for each character class for elective and non-elective modes are given in [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/sr4zi/mathing_out_bashioks_billions_of_possible_build/c4gbubv) excellent off-site answer from more than two years ago.

Given that the Reaper of Souls expansion added another character class, as well as another skill (with five runes), additional passives and another passive slot to each character class, what are the number of possible builds in Reaper of Souls?

**Note 1:** As [noted](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/sr4zi/mathing_out_bashioks_billions_of_possible_build/c4gd316) by the author of the answer [above](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/sr4zi/mathing_out_bashioks_billions_of_possible_build/c4gbubv), *unruned* skills are excluded, as are builds with fewer than 6 skills and/or fewer than the maximum number of passives.

**Note 2:** Useless, meaningless, weak or broken builds, such as [this](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/wizard#jOfTkX!ceb!baZYaa) one from [here](http://www.diablofans.com/forums/diablo-iii-misc-forums/theorycrafting-and-analysis/73075-47274700000000000?comment=3), are not excluded. These would include builds in which passive skills, which did not synergize with active skills, were selected.

Comment: I feel there's no utility to this whatsoever.  What good does it do to know the total number of builds you *can* build?  I'm failing to see a use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Reaper of Souls patch 2.0.6, with four of a possible 19 passive skills (3876 possibilities) and the original formula of:

```
active skill combinations * skill runes * passive skill combinations
```

the number of possible *runed* builds, elective and non-elective, for each character class are as follows:

```
              ---- Active Skills ----
Class         1  2  3  4  5  6  Total  Non-Elective  Elective
Barbarian     4  5  4  4  3  3  23     1.7442E+11    6.1136E+12
Crusader      4  5  4  4  3  4  24     2.3256E+11    8.1515E+12
Demon Hunter  5  4  3  4  4  4  24     2.3256E+11    8.1515E+12
Monk          4  3  4  3  4  4  22     1.3954E+11    4.5188E+12
Witch Doctor  4  4  4  3  5  3  23     1.7442E+11    6.1136E+12
Wizard        4  4  4  5  5  4  26     3.8760E+11    1.3943E+13
```